# Salesforce login bypass Add a Time-Based Token

Tags: security, authentication, winter14, login-errors

I just created my salesforce account a few weeks ago and now when i try to login it requires me to scan a QR code which my phone, an old nokia model can't possibly do. Is there anyway for me to bypass this? since they online chat support isn't much of a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this form of authentication yet, but from what I have read, I believe there should be a 'Can’t scan the QR code' link that will show a key that needs to be manually typed in, for the cases where you are on a device that cant scan the code.

You can read more about it in the Winter 14 release notes

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security.htm

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_time-based_tokens.htm

Comment: wonder why they automatically added it on my account when i didn't add it there, will give this a read and hope this will help. thank you